# .htaccess causing redirect loop on safari only - http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, safari

This only happens in safari. I don't know why. Google Chrome, Firefox, everything works fine.

On any Apple product, using safari, I get a redirect loop:

Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

No idea why it happens. If I remove this it works but doesn't redirect http to https, only redirects www:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What url do you enter? www.example.com ?

Comment: LOL no. It's just for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing both redirects to go straight to the desired location:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```