# Laravel infinity loop on safari or apple product?

Tags: ios, .htaccess, laravel, safari

Each Time I go on my website using safari There is a infinit Redirect loop

I tried this solution [.htaccess causing redirect loop on safari only - http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402177/htaccess-causing-redirect-loop-on-safari-only-http-to-https)

```
# http to https redirect
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I still have the same issue. I downloaded Chrome on my Ipad and I have the same problem with chrome installed in the ipad ...

Comment: Did you change original Laravel `.htaccess` file? If you did, what did you try to achieve?

Comment: I modified the /laravel/public/.htaccess file. Even if I comment everything in the .htaccess file, I still get a redirect loop on safari/apple.

Comment: You should use original `.htaccess` and modify Apache config only